# Using array in document.getElementById.src not working

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, iframe, src

Im trying to use an array (or var) to input into the src of an  tag. when I use the text of the url the browser can display the second src but when I turn it into a var -array it doesn't seem to work:

this is my html:

```
    <iframe id="myFrame" src= "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d24190.105180007897!2d-73.84374818788723!3d40.72323027714316!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89c25e394b6cc0b9%3A0xf15c2215b49863c4!2zUmVnbyBQYXJrLCDXp9eV15XXmdeg16EsINeg15nXlSDXmdeV16jXpywg15DXqNem15XXqiDXlNeR16jXmdeq!5e0!3m2!1siw!2sil!4v1609851520165!5m2!1siw!2sil" > </iframe>

    <div class="btn-container">
        <button class="switch-buttons" id="prevbutton" >Prev Location</button> 
        <button class="switch-buttons" id="nextbutton" onclick="myFunction()">Next Location</button>
    </div>
```

this is my Js:

```
let jlm = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d108513.70308822051!2d35.10531865599252!3d31.796299428569416!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x1502d7d634c1fc4b%3A0xd96f623e456ee1cb!2sJerusalem!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sil!4v1610023043184!5m2!1sen!2sil";

let rome = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d190029.0177339561!2d12.395913509664267!3d41.90998597323602!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x132f6196f9928ebb%3A0xb90f770693656e38!2sRome%2C%20Metropolitan%20City%20of%20Rome%2C%20Italy!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sil!4v1610023162463!5m2!1sen!2sil";

let listOfCitys = [jlm, rome];


function myFunction() {

    document.getElementById("myFrame").src = listOfCitys[0];

}
```

I am trying to create a loop so that each time i click the btn it will iterate the src in the array. but just putting one of the vars into the src is not working.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start of by tracking which location is active at the moment. This could look like:

```
let currentCityIndex = 0;
```

This way you can select a src from the `listOfCitys` array.

```
listOfCitys[currentCityIndex];
```

When you want to go to the next increment the index and select a new item from the array.

```
currentCityIndex++;
listOfCitys[currentCityIndex];
```

And do the same for previous with decrement.

```
currentCityIndex--;
listOfCitys[currentCityIndex];
```

Now the `currentCityIndex` does not know how many items the `listOfCitys` array has. So before incrementing or decrementing you'll have to check the current state and if the next action will be within minimum and maximum range of the array (`0` and `listOfCitys.length - 1`).

```js
const frame = document.getElementById("myFrame");

const prevCity = document.getElementById('prevbutton');
const nextCity = document.getElementById('nextbutton');

let jlm = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d108513.70308822051!2d35.10531865599252!3d31.796299428569416!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x1502d7d634c1fc4b%3A0xd96f623e456ee1cb!2sJerusalem!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sil!4v1610023043184!5m2!1sen!2sil";
let rome = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d190029.0177339561!2d12.395913509664267!3d41.90998597323602!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x132f6196f9928ebb%3A0xb90f770693656e38!2sRome%2C%20Metropolitan%20City%20of%20Rome%2C%20Italy!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sil!4v1610023162463!5m2!1sen!2sil";

let listOfCitys = [jlm, rome];
let currentCityIndex = 0;

prevCity.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // If the current index is already the first item..
  if (currentCityIndex === 0) {
    // ..Then go to the last..
    currentCityIndex = listOfCitys.length - 1;
  } else {
    // ..Otherwise to the previous.
    currentCityIndex--;
  }
  frame.src = listOfCitys[currentCityIndex];
});

nextCity.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // If the current index is already the last item..
  if (currentCityIndex === listOfCitys.length - 1) {
    // ..Then go to the start..
    currentCityIndex = 0;
  } else {
    // ..Otherwise to the next.
    currentCityIndex++;
  }
  frame.src = listOfCitys[currentCityIndex];
});
```

```html
<iframe id="myFrame" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d24190.105180007897!2d-73.84374818788723!3d40.72323027714316!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89c25e394b6cc0b9%3A0xf15c2215b49863c4!2zUmVnbyBQYXJrLCDXp9eV15XXmdeg16EsINeg15nXlSDXmdeV16jXpywg15DXqNem15XXqiDXlNeR16jXmdeq!5e0!3m2!1siw!2sil!4v1609851520165!5m2!1siw!2sil"> </iframe>

<div class="btn-container">
  <button class="switch-buttons" id="prevbutton">Prev Location</button>
  <button class="switch-buttons" id="nextbutton">Next Location</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you for the elaborate answer. I tried your code but it still doesn't work. When I click on the btn nothing happens, when I inspect the btn in the browser no event listener shows up?
I have tried the onclick attribute and inserting the text of the next url - that works, but this only works for one click and not what i need...

Comment: Is your script loaded before the iframe and buttons?

Comment: hey, it is now working. I separated the script into a new file. I don't know why but it was conflicting with other js in the file and no executing...